# How do you configure the nav pane to show the PDF and epub options?

Tags: read-the-docs

I've created a project (https://writing-fundamentals-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on ReadTheDocs that uses mkdocs to generate the output from markdown files in Github using the Readthedocs theme. The problem is that the little version drop-down in the lower right corner doesn't have links for the PDF and epub versions that are supposedly auto-generated with each build. In other projects (including RTD's own documentation), I see this version drop-down in the left nav pane, and it includes the PDF and epub links. I've double-checked that I have selected the options for PDF and epub generation in the settings in the project. Can someone tell me how I can configure the nav pane to show the PDF and epub links for my documentation?

Comment: On further investigation, I'm guessing the problem is not that the nav pane isn't configured to show these links but that the PDF/epub versions are not getting built at all. If I go to the downloads page for my project (https://readthedocs.org/projects/writing-fundamentals-guide/downloads/), there's nothing there. Does this have something to do with using mkdocs instead of Sphinx to generate the content?